# Determine Maven provided dependencies

Tags: maven

I've inherited a few maven projects which have added a `/dependencies` directory to capture Java jar libraries that aren't part of the project war and must be installed by a DevOps into a Tomcat installation.

The libraries in this directory seem to fall into four categories:

1. "provided" scope libraries,
2. downstream dependencies of those provided libraries, and
3. discoverable implementations of api jars
4. "mystery" libraries, i.e., not available in an external repository, and maybe unsure where they ever came from.

Is there a strategy to get Maven to help manage these dependencies and perhaps fetch them for external install?

Answer (score 0):

There are probably several strategies to choose from.

Number one: leave it as it is. If it works and the build is reproducible (on different environments) that seems one valid solution.

The "mystery" part of the build might not be more of an issue for new people working with it.

I think it is valid to create an own maven module to be delivered to the infrastructure team. This module can contain the jars in the `/dependencies` folder.
What you would need to do is create a pom.xml and add all dependencies currently in that directory (of course not the transitive ones). The magic ones would need to go in a repository proxy (nexus, artifactory, ...). If you don't have a maven repository yet: you want one! (its easy to setup and it does help a lot!)

I would then use the assembly plugin or some ant task to build the zip do be delivered. So the infrastructure team is able to just unzip / copy the files where they need to be. This step can then even be scripted (so the upload / unzip is done through SSH or something like that).

This is probably only one way to do it. I would assume to resolve the jar's in the /dependencies directory may be a bit of a pain.

The advantage is obviously that you document and simplify the management of those libraries. I would also assume if you update some of them it is easier across branches to merge since there are no binary files around. So it may be worth the effort.